# HttpServletRequestWrapper and Filter lifecycle in tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I am coding a Tomcat application and am authenticating against Google's oauth2 services.  I was originally going to write a simple `Filter` to do the authentication but there is no way to set the user principal in a `Filter`.  From my understanding you have to have the `Filter` call an implemented `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and set it inside of that class [as seen in this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/466744/Servlets/java/Set-user-principal-filter)

I'm pretty sure Tomcat only instantiates one `Filter` of each type you may have defined and all requests go through this single object down the `Filter` chain (correct me if I'm wrong).

In the linked to code, is it correct for the code to call

`next.doFilter(new UserRoleRequestWrapper(user, roles, request), response);`

where every request is instantiating a new `UserRoleRequestWrapper`?  Should this Filter instead have one request wrapper instatiated that gets shared amonsgst all requests?  I'm having a hard time finding documentation on the specs of classes such as these.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a Filter is what you're looking for. Doesn't seem right for this purpose... Filters weren't created for such use cases; they were created for pre/post processing requests and responses, with emphasis on manipulating the actual request/response *data*, rather than other aspects of the client-server communication (such as security). Remember, authenticating a user may have further repercussions than just handling HTTP request cycles. Security ties into the JavaEE framework in a lower level than HTTP cycles.

If you want to authenticate against oauth2, you should be far better off implementing some sort of a JAAS implementation for it, and plug it into Tomcat.

Comment: One JAAS sample I could find with code was http://blog.frankel.ch/custom-loginmodule-in-tomcat but I don't understand how this would be implemented in my case... I don't understand how the callback functions work there, nor how it would get the tokens sent by the clients (The clients do not send a username, only a token in an HTTP header).  Would I have to write a connector as well to parse the token out?

Comment: What if you combine the two: implement a JAAS module for the login process, store the token in the Principal, and then use a filter to get the token from the principal and inject it as an HTTP header?